# Is it possible to use qt creator IDE to create a non-Qt project and does not require the qt dll files

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I have created an application that uses a standard C++ code only, and does not uses qt library. but when release the application and run it, I have found that the application requires the qt dll files like `Qt5Core.dll`, `icuin52.dll`, 
`icuuc52.dll`, `etc`.

I don't know why the application needs these files, note that I have created `Non-Qt Project` with `Plain C++ Project`.

[image]

**.pro file**

```
QT -= core
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    store.cpp

HEADERS += \
    store.h

QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static

LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lsqlite -lsqlite3

win32:RC_ICONS += icon.ico

RESOURCES += \
    resource.qrc
```

**How can I create an C/C++ application ('C++ Standard code') using qt creator, and does not needs qt dll files to run it ?**

Comment: Can you post your `.pro` project file? I suspect it may be missing `QT -= core`, for instance.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: but I have added `qrc` resource file `resource.qrc` in my project.  is there is problem if use `QT -= core` and I use `qrc` file ?

Comment: How is it a non-Qt project if it uses Qt resources files then?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Ok, what is the corresponding of `qrc` file in standard c++.

Comment: There is no such thing. Why do you want to use them? If your code is pure standard C++, why would it need a qrc file? Can you elaborate? And can you please post up the `.pro` file so we can have a look at what precisely is going on?

Comment: I'll hazard a guess that the `icu` libraries are Unicode libraries brought in by SQLite. Was the Qt5Core dependency removed by `QT -= core`? Are there any other library dependencies left? Can you also post them?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Thanks. I have did something, I have removed `RESOURCES += \ resource.qrc` , and now the application works fine without required dll files. but I want to add an icon to the `exe` file ?

Comment: That I don't know how to do. I don't think I've ever added icons to an application I've made in Qt Creator, Qt or not. Maybe that would be worth another question?

Comment: Use CMake and your problem will be gone.

Comment: In addition to what the duplicate question states, you cannot use qrc files, as these depend on Qt functionality, like you are seeing.